# Align 2 different elements vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an div that comprises of 2 elements: an image and a text. The image occupying the first half (top) of the `div`, and the text occupying the bottom second part of the `div` (bottom).
I would like for the image to fit the size of the `div`, but not to stretch, and also want to apply different hover effects to each element. I've been working on it but I don't get to build this kind of structure. This is what I have so far:

```css
.work-item {
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:350px;
}
.work-item-image {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.work-item-image img {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.work-item-text {
  position:absolute;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="work-item">
   <a href="#">
     <div class="work-item-image"> 
       <img src="..."/>
     </div>
     <div class="work-item-text">
       <h1>Hello Worl</h1>
     </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. What should determine the width of the "work-item"  div? The text or the image? What about the height? Will all "work-item" div we the same width / height?

Comment: What I want is 2 elements align vertically with the same dimensions. So both of them will have the same width, but the heigh will be half of the whole div dimension. If the main div has 350px for heigh, that means I want both the image and the text to have each 175px. The work-item is the main div, which contains the work-item-img and work-item-text.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fix the width for image. And width of each div must be equal. This code might help you. Resize your image with Photoshop, etc.

```
.work-item {
position:relative;
height:300px;
width:350px; or width: 100%; 
}
.work-item-image {
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
.work-item-image img {
max-height: 150px;
object-fit: cover;
}
.work-item-text {
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:middle;
 max-height: 150px;
 width: 350px; or width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the text still stays in top of the image, I want it to be under the image in a different div with same dimensions as the image! Thanks!

Comment: Its working.The text is under the image. Working fine. If its not working for you please show us in Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use this css for .work-item-image

```
.work-item-image {
              float: right;
              width: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline-block` instead of position absolute like this:

```css
.work-item {
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:350px;
}
.work-item-image {
  display: inline-block;
}
.work-item-image img {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.work-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="work-item">
   <a href="#">
     <div class="work-item-image"> 
       <img src="..."/>
     </div>
     <div class="work-item-text">
       <h1>Hello Worl</h1>
     </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost does the job, but I want the image and text align vertically, and not horizontally. But thanks  :)

Comment: You could achieve that by giving both elements the same `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Try to find other solutions then absolute.
CSS:

```
.work-item {
    height:300px;
    width:350px;
}

.work-item-image {
    top:0;
}

.work-item-image img {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.work-item-text {
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 350px;

} 
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="work-item">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="work-item-image"> 
                <img src="..."/>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item-text">
                <h1>Hello Worl</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! There's only one problem:my text doesnt fit the work-item-text div, it keeps on one line only, overflowing to the rest of the webpage, how can I fix it? Only managed to fin solutions with word-wrap: break-word; but that only works when we have bigger size words, and not on text. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand. On my browser the text takes multiple lines, on the size of .work-item {width:350;} (I tried it with some loremipsum).
You can try to add a "width" attribut to .work-item-text, then word-wrap would work for smaller words too.